# change class name after underscore using jquery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace the class name with just the id clicked. But the condition is, there is the beginning of the class name ("filter-") I want to change.

For example:

```
<div class="change filter-" id="changeMe"></div>
<div class="list">
     <div class="click" id="first"></div>
     <div class="click" id="second"></div>
     <div class="click" id="third"></div>
</div>
```

When you click `#first` then `filter-` must be `filter-first` like this:

```
<div class="change filter-first"></div>
```

It can normally be done with `addClass` and `removeClass`. But is there a way to do this with regex?

Comment: Why do you want to use regex? Why *not* just add and remove the appropriate `filter-xxx` classes from the div?

Comment: I just ask if there is such a method. Why isn't a rainbow a single color? :)

Comment: Fair enough. :)

Comment: It reminds me of https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/270935

Answer (score 1):

No need for jQuery here.

```js
const changeMe = document.getElementById('changeMe');

for (const listItem of document.querySelectorAll('.click')) {
  listItem.addEventListener('click', function() {
    changeMe.className = `change first-${listItem.id}`
  })
}
```

```css
.click::before { content: attr(id); }

#changeMe::before { content: attr(class); }
```

```html
<div class="change" id="changeMe"></div>
<hr>
<div class="list">
  <div class="click" id="first"></div>
  <div class="click" id="second"></div>
  <div class="click" id="third"></div>
</div>
```

If for whatever reason you insist on using jQuery:

```js
const $changeMe = $('#changeMe');

$('.click').on('click', function() {
  $changeMe.attr('class', `change first-${this.id}`);
})
```

```css
.click::before {
  content: attr(id);
}

#changeMe::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="change" id="changeMe"></div>
<hr>
<div class="list">
  <div class="click" id="first"></div>
  <div class="click" id="second"></div>
  <div class="click" id="third"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can the answer I am looking for be done with jquery.

Comment: I stopped using jQuery years ago, and never since found a single use-case where I wanted to use it.